# iBeacon: App awake based on your current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ibeacon, region-monitoring

What is the meaning of this?

[image]

I have written an app that has registered for a specific iBeacon region monitoring. I run the app once so it can register to iOS the monitoring however, once I terminate the app and try to test it (**testing if the app gets launched by iOS when entering beacon proximity**)

I notice that the App is sometimes woken up by iOS successfully (I added a UILocalNotification that is triggered when the app is woken up with the option key equal to **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey**. I have chosen notify on entry and notify on exit to the monitoring preferences.

However when I switch off the beacon and I double tap the home button it show the figure above. It stays like this for a long while while the beacon is on but without triggering the notification. It does trigger the notification sometimes (but not always).

Why would iOS keep showing me the App even if it does not apparently get launched? Is it guaranteed that the app gets always launched when entering a beacon region? (I waited for a long 20 minutes.. sometimes I get the notifications with a past date all together.. e.g. 30 minutes later I get notifications with a due date of 30 minutes ago...)

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
    [[DebugNotificationHandler sharedHandler] triggerMessage:@"AppDelegate: Triggered following iBeacon range"];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Location monitoring (which includes beacon monitoring) on iOS works also when the app is not running.** That's what enables iOS to wake up or relaunch your app when an enter/exit event happens.

It's a common misconception/simplification to think about beacon monitoring as something that happens "in the background," but that's not actually how it works. Your app is still being suspended like any other app (with the exception of apps that use background modes), and susceptible to being terminated due to memory pressure. It's iOS itself that keeps scanning for enters/exits, and if they happen, delivers them to your app.

One side effect is, even if you terminate the app, the location-based app suggestions (like the one on the app switcher you're observing, but there's also an icon on the lock screen) still work.

Another thing to keep in mind is, **iOS will only relaunch your app if the beacon state changes**. For example, if you're in range of a beacon w/ the app running, and then terminate the app, the bottom bar on the app switcher will still be there, because you're still in range the beacon, but the app will only be relaunched if you go out of range.

And last but not least, **exit events have a built-in delay of 30 seconds**, i.e., you need to be out of range of a beacon for at least 30 seconds for iOS to register the new state as "outside" the beacon's range. If you turn the beacon off, and then turn it on a few seconds after, no state change will be registered, and thus your app won't be relaunched.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So if a beacon is in range and we turn off the phone shall I expect to not get the app woken app by iOS once I turn the phone back on and subsequently the beacon on? In other words: are state changes persisted by iOS?

Comment: Yes, they are. If there was a state change, your app should eventually get it no matter what. iOS can detect going in and out of range of beacons even when the phone is locked and display is off, so your app might be relaunched even in such situation.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, much appreciated. So switching the phone off should not affect the beacon monitoring right? Do you have some official apple reference on this? I struggle finding details on how beacons are supposed to work when the phone is turned off in the apple documentation.

Comment: Do you mean physically switching the phone off? Naturally, monitoring won't work then, but iOS persists the list of regions being monitored, so once you turn the phone on again, it'll resume monitoring. The best reference on the Apple's side is the [CLLocationManager's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/), particularly the "Using Regions to Monitor Boundary Crossings" section.